# Validating Saved HTML File Size against CURL size_download / download_content_length?

Tags: php, curl, filesize

It always seems to be slightly off.

Whilst downloading an HTML file using CURL, I'm attempting to verify that the saved HTML file is the same size as the headers indicate.

Minified:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Among other things, `$curlinfo` provides the following information:

```
[size_download] => 331650
[download_content_length] => 331650
```

(these are always the same value in my experience)

I've tried using `mb_strlen`

`mb_strlen($result, 'utf8');` = `331495`

`mb_strlen($result);` =  `331495`

Slightly off.

Using DOM to save the file

```
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $DOM->LoadHTML($result);
    $DOM->encoding = 'utf-8';
    $SaveHTMLfile = $DOM->saveHTMLFile($filename);
```

Checking this with `filesize($fileName);`

Slightly more... FileSize: `332295`

Of course if I modify the encoding, or modify the `preserveWhiteSpace` setting the `filesize($filename)` value skews one way or the other.. never to the result filesize indicated in the curl headers (`331650`).

Is there a way or a method I am missing that will allow me to verify the HTML file downloaded from the external source down to the actual byte?

Comment: size_download and download_content_length would be in bytes so use strlen instead of mb_strlen.  Also, is there any Content-Encoding or Transfer-Encoding headers sent?  Using something like DOM that would modify the content will likely throw your results off further.

Comment: No Content-Encoding or Transfer-Encoding from what I can see.... good idea though, haven't thought about that as a reason. You are correct though, strlen provides the proper byte size!  so...  `$download_size = (int) $getPage['CurlInfo']['download_content_length'];`  `$downloaded_size = strlen($HTML);` and a comparison operator to validate   `if ($download_size === $downloaded_size) {` seems a good working solution for now.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad the strlen solution solved it!  You may end up finding some scenarios where you can't use the resulting content size accurately.  For example, if the transfer encoding is gzip or deflate, the content-length header would be the size of the compressed content, and the bytes downloaded will be smaller than the uncompressed content.  In this case, just trust that curl would not return the result without error and will not return incomplete content.  Happy coding.